# Editor template collection not binding on post

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding, mvc-editor-templates

I have a main viewmodel that contains a list of child viewmodels to be edited:

```
public class MyObjectGridViewModel
{
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public List<MyObject> Objects { get; set; } = new List<MyObject>();
}
```

The structure of `MyObject` is really not relevant at all. Then I have an editor template for the `Objects` collection, like this:

```
@model MyObject
<tr>
    <td class="hidden">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsBanned, new { @class = "checkbox" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

And then a form view to edit individual `MyObject` models inline, i.e. without a separate `Edit` view:

```
@model MyObjectGridViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Ban", "Access", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Comment)
    <table class="table bans">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Objects)
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

And a post action on the controller:

```
[HttpPost]   
public ActionResult Ban(MyObjectGridViewModel model)
{
    var items = model.Objects.Count(); // items == 0
}
```

Yet when I click the submit button and invoke this action, the `model.Objects` list has zero items. The editor template displays an expected 5 items, I check 1 or 2 checkboxes, submit, and lose all the items in the `Objects` property.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Your action method is named `Confirm` and yet in your `Html.BeginForm` you seem to be using some `Ban` action on the `Access` controller. Would you mind editing your question in order to match your real code?

Comment: Also you do not seem to have a corresponding input field for the `Name` property on the `MyObject` model, only a `DisplayFor` helper. No value will be sent to the server upon submit in this case. Besides when I tried your code it worked perfectly fine for me, so I guess that the problem lies in some other portion of your code which unfortunately is not shown here.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I have corrected the action method name, that is the only error. Only having a `DisplayFor` for `Name` is fully intentional. I only want to display the name, and edit only the `IsBanned` property.

Comment: Try adding a hidden for the name, which is not editable. It won't submit the value, so the model binder may not like that. Just a guess.

Comment: You code looks fine. Is the correct html being generated (with zero based, consecutive indexers) - e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="Objects[0].Id ... /> <input type="hidden" name="Objects[1].Id ... />` etc)? Also try removing the `= new List<MyObject>();` from the property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, good insight on checking the indexers on the generated markup. It was correct, but I have answered the question. However, there is absolutely no reason to to remove the property initializer. That is just syntactic sugar for not having to initialize the property in the constructor.

Comment: Yes, I know what it is. Its the only thing I could thing of that may have interfered with the `DefaultModelBinder` because the code you have shown works fine as is (have tested it). And I don't see how your answer could have resolved it. And as a side note, don't ever use `m => Model`(capital `M`) - if you had some other code (say) `<div>@Model.Name</div>` it will throw an exception - use `m => m`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I often use m => `**M**odel.Prop`, and have for several years, without ever having a problem, to refer to the `ViewPage.Model` variable instead of the parameter of the lambda function. Why would using  `<div>@Model.Name</div>` in the same view cause a problem? It never has for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found some old code, and it looks like the solution is to have an editor template for the main view model, and inside that, use another one for the collection item. I now have:

MyObjectGridViewModel.cshtml:

```
@model MyObjectGridViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Objects)
```

MyObject.cshtml:

```
@model MyObject
<tr>
    <td class="hidden">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsBanned, new { @class = "checkbox" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

And in the form, instead of

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Objects)
```

I now have

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model)
```

And all seems to work fine.